# GentleBoost n-ary classifier?

Tags: algorithm, classification, adaboost

I'm looking for resources or implementation on **n-ary** Gentle Boost classifiers.

I've seen a number of Adaboost implementations, an implementation for GentleBoost in Matlab's Ensemble, but it always seems to be *binary*.

WEKA, too, has only an AdaBoost implementation, not Gentle Boost.

Does anyone have any suggestions of 
- how to go about getting a n-ary Gentle Boost implementation?
- how long approximately it would take to build one if it isn't there already?

Answer (score 1):

There is a package written in R language, named ada, which also has Gentle Boosting:
http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ada/index.html

**Edit**

Indeed, it is only for binary classification:

> ada is used to fit a variety stochastic boosting models for a binary
>   response as described in Additive Logistic Regression: A Statistical
>   View of Boosting by Friedman, et al. (2000).

Comment: I'm looking through this, but it seems to cater only to binary classification again, or am I missing out where it can offer n-ary classification?